# application becomes unresponsive during directory listing in flex 3

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I have designed an AIR application that displays a list with all txt files located in C:\ directory. I have used following code:

```
var videoListsArr:ArrayList = new ArrayList();
var folder:File = new File(driveName+":\\");
folder.getDirectoryListingAsync();
folder.addEventListener( FileListEvent.DIRECTORY_LISTING, handleDirectoryListing );
private function handleDirectoryListing( event:FileListEvent ):void
{       
    for each(var item:File in event.files)
    {               
        var itemExtn:String = (item.extension != null) ? item.extension.toLocaleLowerCase() : null;
        if(item.isDirectory)
        {               
            item.getDirectoryListingAsync();
            item.addEventListener( FileListEvent.DIRECTORY_LISTING, handleDirectoryListing );
        } 
        else if(!item.isSymbolicLink && itemExtn != null)
        {       
            if(itemExtn == "txt")
                videoListsArr.addItem(txt); 
        }
    }   
}
```

This function works fine but it is being executed the application is hang and become unresponsive. Please tell me how to resolve this problem that it displays the list of txt file without making application unresponsive ?

Answer (score 0):

from what i can see, you're getting a directory, looking at all the files in there, and if one of them is a directory, you look at all the files etc recursively, which could end up being very heavy depending on the start folder. remove the first if check and tell me if it's still unresponsive

Comment: can you please tell it elaborately?

Comment: `handleDirectoryListing()` basically gets a file object for each item in a folder. if that item is also a folder, then it gets the directory listing and calls `handleDirectoryListing()` again. this is recursion and could end up being quit large. Imagine if you called this function on your My Documents folder. That would open up *every* folder and subfolder there. And create file objects for each one. You application is hanging because this function is taking up a lot of time, which tells me that the recursion goes quite deep

Comment: that i know, but is there any other way to do that without making the application unresponsive? i need to drill down every folder to get each txt file names, located in the user selected drive. Please help.

Comment: from your starting folder, how many folders and files are you looking through (this is recursive, so it could be a lot)? add in a `trace()` statement or include a count to get a rough idea. do you need to look through all those files? are you starting from something like `documentsDirectory` when you could be just browsing directly to the folder you're interested in? if you don't want to browse, just do it the first time, then store the `nativePath` in a local `SharedObject` so you only need to do it once.

Answer (score 0):

I use a timer to break up the processing. My timer subclasses Timer to add a files:Array and a directories : Array.

The initial handler that processed the top-level directory (in my case, *loadDirectoryHandler*) loads the timer.files with all the files it cannot processes immediately as well as all the sub-directories,

On each cycle through the TIMER handler, it slices out a chunk of the files Array (e.g. 200 files), processes that, and then starts the timer if there are any left so they get processed on the next TIMER event.

For each directory, it takes the File object and

> file.addEventListener( FileListEvent.DIRECTORY_LISTING, loadDirectoryHandler );
>   file.getDirectoryListingAsync();

Cheers